# Catching the error status while running scripts in parallel on Jenkins

Tags: perl, shell, jenkins, tcsh

I'm running two perl scripts in parallel on Jenkins and one more script which should get executed if the first two succeed. If I get an error in script1, script 2 still runs and hence the exit status becomes successful.

I want to run it in such a way that if any one of the parallel script fails, the job should stop with a failure status.

Currently my setup looks like

```
perl_script_1 &

perl_script_2 &

wait

perl_script_3
```

If script 1 or 2 fails in the middle, the job should be terminated with a Failure status without executing job 3.

Note: I'm using tcsh shell in Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup where I run several java processes (tests) in parallel and wait for them to finish. If any fail, I fail the rest of my script.

Each test process writes its result to a file to be tested once done.
Note - the code examples below are written in **bash**, but it should be similar in **tcsh**.

To do this, I get the process id for every execution:

```
test1 &
test1_pid=$!
# test1 will write pass or fail to file test1_result

test2 &
test2_pid=$!

...
```

Now, I wait for the processes to finish by using the `kill -0 PID` command
For example **test1**:

```
# Check test1
kill -0 $test1_pid

# Check if process is done or not
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo process test1 finished
    # check results
    grep fail test1_result

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo test1 failed
        mark_whole_build_failed
    fi
fi
```

Same for other tests (you can do a loop to test all running processes periodically).
Later condition the rest of the execution based on **mark_whole_build_failed**.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi .. Thanks! Is there any way to find it without writing to the test1_result file? Because the wait command will take care of the checking of the status of the jobs.

Comment: I was expecting something like if (perl_script1 && perl_script2) then do perl_script_3

Comment: You can try that too :). I was presenting my solution to a similar case. I like keeping it simple, even if the script is longer and more detailed.

Comment: About avoiding writing of the result file, I don't know how you can get the result of the process that was sent to the background. Maybe there is a way, but I don't know it. Using files as flags is a simple way to keep results. I use it all the time...